# Are the key frames in a CAKeyframeAnimation always hit exactly?

Tags: ios, openal, cakeyframeanimation

Can anyone tell me if the key frames in a CAKeyframeAnimation are always guaranteed to be hit with their exact values when the animation runs? Or... do they only act as interpolation guides? e.g. If I specify, say, 3 points on a path for some arbitrary property to follow - let's call it 'position' - and I specify an execution time of 0.3f seconds, whilst (obviously) points 1 and 3 must be hit (as they are the terminal points) can I guarantee that point 2 will be evaluated exactly as specified in the key frame array? Surprisingly, I haven't found a single document that gives an adequate answer. I ask this because I'm writing an OpenAL sound-effect synchroniser that uses a keyframe animation's path to trigger various short sounds along its length and whilst most of them get executed, now and again a few don't and I don't know if it's my logic that's wrong or my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very interesting! We have a similar problem. Are you having any luck with this? Any tips on how to synchronise audio to key frames that you'd like to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, relying on the "exactness" of a floating-point value that is the result of a calculation is fraught with danger. So for example the following code:

```
CGFloat x1 = some_function();
CGFloat x2 = some_other_function();
if(x1 == x2)
{
    // do something
}
```

without even knowing what the functions do is most likely incorrect. Even if the functions do very similar calculations the optimizer may have reordered operations causing small rounding errors sufficient to cause the equality test to fail.

It should be:

```
CGFloat x1 = some_function();
CGFloat x2 = some_other_function();
CGFloat tolerance = 0.1; // or some tolerance suitable for the calculation.
if(fabsf(x1 - x2) < tolerance)
{
    // do something
}
```

where tolerance is some value suitable for the calculation being performed.

So, without knowing the internals of `CAKeyframeAnimation`, I can tell you that any code that expects exact values would be inherently "fragile". This is not to say that you won't get exact values, you might, but it will depend a lot on the input data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you idz! I was, in fact, using a tolerance - but perhaps my tolerance level is still too rigid. However, you've given me food for thought about something else in the same piece of kit. The odd thing about my 'Audimator' is that running identically the same animation over in sequence with no other code yields the result that sometimes all the sounds get played and at others one (not even the same one) gets missed - but it's never the terminal sounds. I'm getting a new iPhone 4 soon, so I'll see if the phenomenon exhibits on the device. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm still learning how this forum works and thank you for the advice. I'll go back and acknowledge my previous answers. Thanks again for the heads-up! The dropping keypoint activity seems to be a function of CPU load. If I run my tests with a mess of apps running alongside my test, keypoints get missed left, right and centre and in no particular order. Intelligent frame dropping may be the culprit.

Comment: @VectorVictor, no worries, I am fairly new here myself so still not sure of all the ropes either. I suspect you may be correct about the frame dropping.